# Creating Date Relationship in Power BI for Slicers

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I'd like to slice across visuals based on dates in MS Power BI (i.e., one filter for say month will slice all visuals for that time period.

1. I created a date table from http://www.agilebi.com.au/power-bi-date-dimension/ to link to the date columns in each table.
2. I connected xlsx workbook.
   [Image of columns in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl7Pk.png)
3. I added tried to edit the relationship so connect the 2 date columns. However, when I insert the filter using the date_table as values and try to use it, the visuals disappear.
   [Visuals are Gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwaLU.png)

However, when I create the slicer and slice across multiple visuals, they go blank.

**I tried changing the type to "Both" but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Are you using any measure in the visuals? How did you set the slicers? If you set the Cross filter direction to **Both** does it keep the same?

Comment: Please edit the question so that we have a [mcve], with some sample csv data and the precise steps you took to create the report. It's kinda hard to see the whole picture at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script at AgileBI.com.au creates a date table with a 'Date' field that has a data type of text. You can (surprisingly) do a relationship between 2 fields of different data types and not get an error. However, a join between a text field that contains dates, and a regular date field will mean that rows that look like they should match up do not.

You can confirm this is happening by picking a value in the 2 tables that you think should match up and seeing if they are identical. In my case, I had *Tuesday, November 01, 2016* in my imported table, and *11/1/2016* in the other table. While they both represent the same date (in the US), they clearly look different. A good place to see this is in the *Edit Relationship* screen (and it definitely would have been helpful to include a screenshot of that in your original post).

Anyway, if the dates in your table don't match up to the corresponding (text) dates in the Date table, then when you filter to "2016" on your slicer, the visuals will all go blank.

I would recommend:

1. Click **Edit Queries**
2. On the left hand side, select the table of dates (called Invoked Function by the script)
3. Click on the header for the Date column (it will likely already be selected)
4. Select **Transform** on the ribbon
5. Change the **Data Type** from *Any* to *Date*
6. Click **Home** > **Close & Apply**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for